# how to show NewsAggregatorDataset using read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

i create following code and want to see the head of dataset but it doesent work.

i download the dataset from [here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/News+Aggregator) and put it in the project folder.

help me

thanks

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
path_csv = Path('NewsAggregatorDataset/newsCorpora.csv').absolute()
data = pd.read_csv(path_csv)
print(data.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way with `os` module if it is in the **NewsAggregatorDataset** directory

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path_csv = os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/NewsAggregatorDataset/newsCorpora.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(path_csv)
print(data.head())
```

Also see below lines on how to get **current_directory** and **parent_directory**

```
import os
current_directory =  os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # get current directory
parent_directory = os.path.abspath(current_directory + "/../") # get parent directory
```

Comment: thanks but it doesnt work. i think the code is correct but I do not know what the problem. the code is correct for other datasets.